# Why does nautilus struggle to copy files?

Tags: nautilus

This problem appears sporadically when I plug in my (Cannon) camera and try and copy files. Everything will be okay for a while and then it will just have nothing to do with copying files. I can open them in an editor but if I ask Ubuntu to copy the files I get this:

[image: It just hangs like this]

That's a dialogue that is waiting for some sign from heaven before it continues. If I let it, it would stay like that until the camera powers itself down some hours later.

Sometimes it is fine but more and more often it is not.

Why does it refuse to get started and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Check your memory and RAM usage!

Comment: I have 16GB of RAM. It's mostly just cache.